# Evaluating Limit Without L'Hopital

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can anybody solve this limit without using L'Hopital?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\log(x)} \right)
\end{equation}
It is indeed easy to solve with L'Hopital's rule but I needed a solution with only algebraic manipulation or notable cases and I cannot find it. Thanks!

Comment: is $log(x)$ here natural logarith or base $10$?

Comment: It's natural logarithm

Comment: Is a series expansion permitted here?

Comment: Define **your** "notable cases" .

Comment: @DonAntonio , by notable cases I mean the following:
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log{x+1}}{x}=1$
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log{x}}{x}=0$
$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e$

Comment: @Dr.MV No series expansion permitted...

Answer (score 3):

> Herein, we will invoke the limit definition of the exponential function
>
> $$e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n \tag 1$$

Note that making the substitution $x=e^{-y}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)&=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{e^y-1}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\frac{e^y-1-y}{y^2\frac{e^y-1}{y}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Recall the $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=1$.  Then, the problem boils down to evaluating the limit

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\frac{e^y-1-y}{y^2}\right)$$

---

From the Binomial Theorem, we have

$$\left(1+\frac {y}{n}\right)^n-1-y=\frac{n-1}{2n}y^2+\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{y^k}{n^k}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\frac{\left(1+\frac {y}{n}\right)^n-1-y}{y^2}=\frac{n-1}{2n}+\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{y^{k-2}}{n^k} \tag 2$$

For $|y|<1$, we can use the following estimates for the series on the right-hand side of $(2)$:

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{y^{k-2}}{n^k} \right|&\le \sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac{|y|^{k-2}}{k!}\\\\
&\le \sum_{k=3}^\infty \left(|y|\right)^{k-2}\\\\
&=\frac{|y|}{1-|y|}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Using $(1)$ and $(3)$, taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ of both sides of $(2)$ reveals

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac {y}{n}\right)^n-1-y}{y^2}=\frac{e^{y}-1-y}{y^2}=\frac12+O(|y|)\tag 4$$

whence taking the limit as $y\to 0$ of $(4)$ yields

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1-y}{y}=\frac12$$

Finally, we have

> $$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)=\frac12$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Interesting to see a host of approaches.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you sir!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By substituting $x=e^t$ we are left with
$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}\right)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{t}{e^t-1}-1+t\right)=B_1+1=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$$
due to the generating function of [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). As an alternative,

$$ \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} = \frac{t}{2}\coth\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\frac{t}{2} = 1+g(t^2)-\frac{t}{2} $$
with $g(z)$ being an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin, with $g(0)=0$, leads to the same result without directly involving Bernoulli numbers: $\frac{t}{2}\coth\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$ is an even function whose limit as $t\to 0$ equals $1$.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, thanks! Yet, I was searching for something with simpler pre-calculus arguments... here, we must keep in mind a Taylor expansion and this was for pre-undergraduate students.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1}\bracks{{x \over x - 1} - {1 \over \log\pars{x}}} & =
\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{1 + {1 \over x} - {1 \over \log\pars{1 + x}}} =
\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{%
1 + {1 \over x} - {1 \over x - x^{2}/2 + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{3}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{%
1 + {1 \over x} - {1 \over x}\,{1 \over 1 - x/2 + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{x \to 0}\braces{%
1 + {1 \over x} - {1 \over x}\,\bracks{1 + {x \over 2} + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{2}}}} =\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{1 \over 2}}
\end{align}